# How to make Python scripts usable on Windows?

Tags: python

I have some Python scripts in Linux. How can I make those scripts so that windows user can use and execute them?

Comment: Python runs on Windows just like on Linux; you don't have to do anything. Are you asking how to package Python scripts as Windows executables? That's probably an SO question

Answer (score 4):

Hmm, are they not executable at the current moment? Are there any errors? What's wrong?

First of all: does Windows even have Python installed? Open up a Command Prompt and type in `python`. If you get into a Python interpreter shell, you do have it.

Next, to run the files, you have to `cd` into their directory and just run `python file.py`.

If you were to give more details, maybe I could help a bit more?

Answer (score 1):

It depends... How that Python script was written. At some of the cases You can avoid the incompatibility using ["os.*"](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) methods and constants. Most of those are rewritten to some different environments.

Those handy methods includes most of these cases:

- file and directory structure management
- processes management
- environment variables management
- file handlers management
- etc...